# Send donations to external PayPal account php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, donations

My ideal process for this would be...

1) User selects a charity from a list
2) User selects amount to donate
3) pop-up, iframe or new window opens and takes them through paypal preocess
4) user is returned to my site with a callback.

My problem is I don't have access to the paypal acounts as they're charitys, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this no problem.  I actually just tested this in the sandbox yesterday.

You can use the Express Checkout API to process the payments, and set the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID to the email address of the charity account you want the money to go to.

Take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library), which will make the EC calls very simple for you.  Specifically, you'll be working with [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).

The documentation says SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID is used with Parallel payments, but it seems to work just fine with a single payment/receiver from the tests I can.